# build vs2005 solution with msbuild from .net 3.5

Tags: msbuild

I have msbuild proj file which should build solution created on Visual Studio 2005 and containing both C++ and C# project
If I need to build the solution with msbuild which comes with  .NET 3.5, what should be added into proj file ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you doing an automated build like using TFS or just manual?

Comment: Currently manual , but later it planned to be part of scheduled build ( via ElectricCommander)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build a solution file which contains C++ projects then you should use **devenv.exe** to build it. To do this you can use the [Exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) task.

Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

My Book: [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine : Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286)